# No such file when doing `ls /mnt` in docker run

Tags: linux, docker

I have a super simple test Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I build it with `docker build . -t dockertest`.

Then I try to run it with a test command and get a weird error:

```
> docker run -it dockertest "ls /mnt"
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "ls /mnt": stat ls /mnt: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

But when I do just `ls`, everything is fine:

```
> docker run -it dockertest "ls"
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
```

Doing `docker run -it dockertest "/bin/bash -c ls /mnt"` yields the same error.

What exactly am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to quote the command; the space is taken as part of the command name.  It's exactly the same as if you ran `"ls /mnt"` with the quotes from your local shell.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yep, that was exactly it. So simple, so frustrating :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the run command can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/

Essentially it states

> docker container run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

It works with "ls" since `ls` is a valid unix command. However you are passing the command and the args together in the command value. Docker is failing since there is no command "ls /mnt" You need to pass this as command and arg "ls" "/mnt"

```
ubuntu@vps-f116ed9f:/opt/docker_projects/stack_example$ docker container run -it stack_test "ls /bin"
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "ls /bin": stat ls /bin: no such file or directory: unknown.


ubuntu@vps-f116ed9f:/opt/docker_projects/stack_example$ docker container run -it stack_test "ls" "/bin"
bash          chmod          findmnt   mount          sleep         zcat
bunzip2       chown          grep      mountpoint     stty          zcmp
bzcat         cp             gunzip    mv             su            zdiff
bzcmp         dash           gzexe     nisdomainname  sync          zegrep
bzdiff        date           gzip      pidof          tar           zfgrep
bzegrep       dd             hostname  ps             tempfile      zforce
bzexe         df             kill      pwd            touch         zgrep
bzfgrep       dir            ln        rbash          true          zless
bzgrep        dmesg          login     readlink       umount        zmore
bzip2         dnsdomainname  ls        rm             uname         znew
bzip2recover  domainname     lsblk     rmdir          uncompress
bzless        echo           mkdir     run-parts      vdir
bzmore        egrep          mknod     sed            wdctl
cat           false          mktemp    sh             which
chgrp         fgrep          more      sh.distrib     ypdomainname
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't pay enough attention to an actual format specified in docs :(